# Bootstrap 3 Navbar button not working as intended in Android webview

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using webview to load my webpage, for the most part works fine, but the page navbar is getting extra width and placing the navbar button to the right, you have to scroll to find the button:

This is how it looks:
https://i.gyazo.com/abce79b5e38f873612bb27b48ca7d451.png

And the button making white empty space below:
https://i.gyazo.com/9e7bbd1f9d5e48a833065a23a4275881.png

I tried:

```
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

And didn't worked

Tried as well:

```
webview.setInitialScale(1);
```

And I get this, as you can see the button appears but the white space remains:
https://i.gyazo.com/8bcec562fba5d48716048c501931063c.png

In horizontal orientation I get it right:
https://i.gyazo.com/c549be715f15e115c7238f679a4384aa.png

This is how it looks in browser and how it should look in my application:
https://i.gyazo.com/f671f8881ad15b10ce2207182cb4b11f.png

This is my code in android:

```
WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.pagina);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    final Activity activity = this;
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
    });

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Ha ocurrido un error" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl("http://blahblahblah.com");
}
```

Basically a copy/paste of the official documentation

And this is my navbar part in the html file:

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menusuperior">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-left" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive imagenlogo" src="assets/img/logo2.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menusuperior">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#backgroundinfo">Sobre mi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#backgroundservicios">Servicios</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#backgroundcitas">Citas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#backgroundconsultorio">Consultorio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#backgroundcontactoyubicacion">Contacto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://blahblahblah.blogspot.com.co" target="_blank"> Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>          
</header>
```

I made some custom styling to my navbar:

```
.navbar {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background-color: #3d4451;
}

.navbar-nav {
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
    color: #00afa6 !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body { 
        padding-top: 0px;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .navbar {
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        font-size: 18px !important;
        letter-spacing: 2px !important;
        position: relative !important;
        left: 0px;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: add some code. only images do not help.

Comment: Can we have your website link or any working fiddle? we cannot debug an image

Comment: from the android app or the website?

Comment: Ok added all the code involved, hopefully you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that works for me.

> `webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable javascript in webview, use:

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```